# Why can I see basic:latin (c0 controls) in my text?

Tags: unicode, invisible

I've been having some weird issues where the users insert invisible characters and to me they are visible.

This is an example of how it shows in my browser:

[image: start of text character highlighted]]

This is how it shows to others/my clients (same browser):

[image]

What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: You need to set the character encoding so it's consistent in every browser.

Comment: Check byte per byte ang get an idea if symbols changed. Some encodings encode C0 bytes as text (but usually when you write data explicitly). But I expect that the characters are explicit on html (possibly a "rich format" copy, which will convert C0 into visible characters)

Comment: PS: This is a site for programmers, so you should details some more about what you did (programmatically). It helps us to understand better (it is our language). Else superuser, or UX SE may be more relevant (two sister site of us).

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry I forgot to say it was the same browser

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm also a programmer but I didn't do anything to the text. This never happened before...

Comment: Same browser doesn't matter unless it's also on the same machine.  My point is that both HTTP and HTML give you a way to specify exactly which character encoding is being used.  If you don't specify you might get inconsistent behavior.